The window animation glitch appears after update to Debian 12
I have updated from Debian 11 to Debian 12, and I've got the glitches like this when I minimizing / restoring window (especially, Chrome).
The system info:
System:
  Host: debian Kernel: 6.1.0-21-amd64 arch: x86_64 bits: 64 Desktop: Cinnamon
    v: 5.6.8 Distro: Debian GNU/Linux 12 (bookworm)
Graphics:
  Device-1: Intel CometLake-H GT2 [UHD Graphics] driver: i915 v: kernel
  Device-2: NVIDIA TU117M driver: nvidia v: 525.147.05
  Device-3: IMC Networks USB2.0 HD UVC WebCam type: USB driver: uvcvideo
  Display: x11 server: X.Org v: 1.21.1.7 with: Xwayland v: 22.1.9 driver: X:
    loaded: intel,modesetting,nvidia dri: iris gpu: i915 resolution:
    1: 1920x1080~60Hz 2: 1920x1080~60Hz
  API: OpenGL v: 4.6 Mesa 22.3.6 renderer: Mesa Intel UHD Graphics (CML GT2)


There were gif file

I've updated the question
